# Cannot Access Email from Facebook Graph

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been using the below code to get some details from Facebook graph,

```
    func getFBUserData(){
    let parameters =  ["fields": "id, first_name, picture.type(large), email, last_name, gender"]
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: parameters)
    graphRequest?.start { (connection, result, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print("Data Not Received")
        } else {
            let userID = FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID
            let URL = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
            print(URL)

            let json = JSON(result)
            print("FB Json \(json)")
            let fid = json["id"].stringValue
            let email = json["email"].stringValue
            let name =  json["first_name"].stringValue
            let lName = json["last_name"].stringValue
            let sex = json["gender"].stringValue
            var imgURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fid + "/picture?type=large"
            print(imgURLString)


            self.UploadSocialAccount(name: name,lname: lName, email: email, picture: imgURLString, gender: sex)
            let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            manager.logOut()

        }
    }
}
```

for some reason I'm able get all other details except for email.
What do need to change in the function, to get all the parameters?

Comment: Did the user grant your app email permission?

Comment: I think no.. how to grant app email permission? in this function..?

Comment: You ask the user for permission when the user logs in

Comment: so, should I have to set it in info.plist?

Answer (score 0):

Email with be accessed and has a value if it's currently active and can be used to log in yahoo or gmail or whatever it's supporter , but if it's expired you will get nil data despite it's valid to login Facebook

```
        let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

         facebookLogin.logOut() 

        facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email", "user_friends"], from:self, handler:
        {  
            (facebookResult, facebookError) -> Void in

            let requestMe:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id,email, first_name, last_name, gender, picture"])

            let connection : FBSDKGraphRequestConnection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()



            connection.add(requestMe, completionHandler: { (con, results, error) in

                //access_token

                if ((error) == nil)

                {
                     let dic = results as! NSDictionary 

                    DataClass.shared.facebookId = dic.value(forKey: "id") as! String

                    print("FBis111123 \(DataClass.shared.facebookId)")

                    let fname = dic.value(forKey: "first_name")

                    let lname = dic.value(forKey: "last_name")

                    let email = (dic.value(forKey: "email"))

                    let picture = dic.value(forKey: "picture") as! NSDictionary

                    let data = picture["data"]! as! NSDictionary

                }
                else

                {


                }

            })


            connection.start()

            print("token:\(String(describing: facebookResult?.token))")


            if facebookError != nil
            {
                print("Facebook login failed. Error \(String(describing: facebookError))")
            }
            else if (facebookResult?.isCancelled)!
            { 
                print("Facebook login was cancelled.")

            }
            else
            {
                 print("Success.")

            }
    })
```

Comment: you can  still login with it's email address , i mean say if it's yahoo email you can open it in yahoo app or

Answer (score 0):

Have you requested permission for reading the email address? Otherwise, you're only able to read the public profile of facebook. To access additional information you have to ask for permission of the user specifically. Check this website:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions

"Before you send Graph API requests, you should check for necessary permissions and request them if needed."

You'd want to do this in the login button, for example:

```
func presentFBButton() {
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.delegate = self
    // Permissions below this comment
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: self.view.center.y + 123, width: view.frame.width - 100, height: 38)
}
```